# How to use AOP or others method to set value after JPARepository in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, cobol, jparepository

I have a little strange problem. All the entity in program extends "BaseEntity" and there is a field "resultStatus" in it.
Now I have a requirement need to set value after any "find" methods in JPARepository (like findAll(), findById(),findByIndexAndCode()....).
If result not null, set resultStatus to "OK". result is null, set resultStatus to "Warning". When exception happen, set resultStatus to "Failed".

I tried to extends JPARepository and call the method like:

```
default List<T> findAll() {
    List<T> entity=null;
    try {
        entity = JpaRepository.super.findAll();    //error here
        if (entity.get(0) != null) {
            entity.get(0).setSqlReturnCode("OK");
        } else {
            BaseEntity entity1 = new BaseEntity();
            entity1.setSqlReturnCode("Warning");
            entity.add((T) entity1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        BaseEntity entity1 = new BaseEntity();
        entity1.setSqlReturnCode("Failed");
        entity.add((T) entity1);
    }
    return entity;
}
```

And this solution didn't work.

Now I think maybe I can use AOP to catch the result after search JPA, but I dont know what the pointcut is. Can you help me ? Or offer others soluction.

I know it sound strange beacuse I can use `.length()'` .size() .isEmpty()`...to do. But this is the requirment from customer .

I tried to extends JPARepository with a new interface and call it's method. But interface looks cant do this just like class.

Comment: "*Can you help me ?*" - Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- "*Or offer others soluction.*" - We are not a code-writing service. --- "*But this is the requirment from customer .*" - Press the customer to explain to you **why** this is the requirement. You are the expert, you need to understand it. If I go to the mechanic, I don't tell them how to to their job either, I let them do their thing.

Comment: On the subject of AOP: Aspects are for cross-cutting concerns. We could use interceptors to intercept the result. But I really do not see the point. I also do not see the point of this solution. This seems to be mixing business or protocol logic with persistence. If it has to be implemented in this way, at least separate the concerns.

Comment: Because customer want the coding style like cobol. we support cutomer transfer to java from cobol system. To decrease gap between two language, we try to make it easier to understand.

Comment: this has nothign to do with AOP

Comment: Hi @Joseph, One solution could be to create a base repository and add your custom implementation.  Then, you can use it on your repositories. Check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: @ingattex But I need to custom all of methods in JpaRepository for all of Repositories.

Comment: and dont want programer need to custom it in the future

Comment: This has nothing to do with the COBOL programming language.